# Dart: el ciclo for se ejecuta correctamente solo la primera vez

Tags: flutter, dart

Tengo esta función en el cual dentro hay un `for` que me está dando problema, os pido ayuda si alguien puede ver el error del código, primeramente voy a poner la función al completo.

```
_sumahorasbolsa_brigada(String hrsUsuarios)async {
for (int i = 0; i < _usuariosbrigada.length; i++) {
  usuarioseleccionado = _usuariosbrigada[i].uid;
  print('Se suma las horas del id: $usuarioseleccionado');
  
  this._hrsrealizada = await hrsUsuarioService.getHrsBolsaRealizadas('${usuarioseleccionado}');
  setState(() {});
  print('Guardias realizadas: ${_hrsrealizada.length}');

  if (_hrsrealizada.length != 0) {

    for (int z = 0; z < _hrsrealizada.length; z++) {
      selectedUser = _hrsrealizada[i].hrsbolsa;
      int horas = int.parse(selectedUser);
      hrstotal = horas + hrstotal;
      resto = hrsbolsanual - hrstotal;
    }
    print('Total horas del id: $usuarioseleccionado =  $hrstotal');
  }
}
```

Cuando recorre la primera vez el ciclo se realiza correctamente, es decir, imprimo en consola como ha tomado el primer registro de la lista `"_usuariobrigada.length"`, después trae perfectamente los datos de la BD como compruebo e imprimo en pantalla después del

`this._hrsrealizada = await hrsUsuarioService.getHrsBolsaRealizadas('${usuarioseleccionado}'); setState(() {}); print('Guardias realizadas: ${_hrsrealizada.length}');`,

y por último pasa los datos al `if` para que lo sume todo los valores de un campo, que imprimo para comprobar que es correcto; adjunto imagen donde comprueba la salida.

[image: Salida en consola]

Pues bien, el fallo está cuando al comenzar de nuevo el ciclo, salta a la primera linea `async` y comienza de nuevo el ciclo `for`, con la consecuencia que vuelve a iniciar el `length` de la lista y me da un error al procesarlo en el `if`. Como la consulta es de tipo `Future`, es imprescindible el `async`.

Comment: probaste quitando el setState y poniendolo al final del for ?

Comment: Por otro lado, veo que tienes un error aquí : selectedUser = _hrsrealizada[i].hrsbolsa; ,  debe ser :  selectedUser = _hrsrealizada[z].hrsbolsa;   Z por i

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gracias `diegodeveloped`, tu apreciación ha resuelto el problema, mas que cambiarlo de lugar como solo lo que quiero es sumar unos valores le quito `setState` y bingo todo resuelto.
adjunto código por si es de utiidad a alguien:

```
_sumahorasbolsa_brigada(String hrsUsuarios) async {
for (int i = 0; i < _usuariosbrigada.length; i++) {
  hrstotal = 0;
  usuarioseleccionado = _usuariosbrigada[i].uid;
  print('Se suma las horas del id: $usuarioseleccionado');

  this._hrsrealizada = await hrsUsuarioService
      .getHrsBolsaRealizadas('${usuarioseleccionado}');
  print('Guardias realizadas: ${_hrsrealizada.length}');

  if (_hrsrealizada.length != 0) {
    for (int z = 0; z < _hrsrealizada.length; z++) {
      selectedUser = _hrsrealizada[z].hrsbolsa;
      int horas = int.parse(selectedUser);
      hrstotal = horas + hrstotal;
      resto = hrsbolsanual - hrstotal;
    }
    print('Total horas del id: $usuarioseleccionado =  $hrstotal');
  }else{
    // hrstotal = 0;
    // print('Total horas del id: $usuarioseleccionado =  $hrstotal');
  }
}
```